# Cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone let me know what I am missing to `componentWillUnmount` my code.

The Error is

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Layout (created by RoomsPage)
    in RoomsPage (created by HotExportedRoomsPage)
    in AppContainer (created by HotExportedRoomsPage)
    in HotExportedRoomsPage (created by PageRenderer)
```

Seen it a thousand times as most of us have but I don't appear to be able to `unmount`. My code in question is;

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(this.handleScroll, 32));
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', debounce(this.handleScroll, 32));
    }
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollPositionY = +window.scrollY;
    return this.setState({ scrollPositionY });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not removing the event listener because the you're passing different functions to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. This is because two functions with identical definitions are not equal. See for yourself:

```
(() => true) === (() => true) 
// false
```

You need to define your function, then pass it.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount() {       
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll = debounce(
  () => { this.setState({ scrollPositionY: +window.scrollY }) },
  32
);
```

By the way, you also don't need to check for `window` in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillUnmount` in most circumstances… SSR doesn't mount components.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning different instances to listener

solution:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      this.hasScrolled = debounce(this.handleScroll, 32);
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.hasScrolled);
  }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.hasScrolled);
  }
}
```